# How to make website change its layout of image/text when the browser dimensions are changed?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to develop my own website and have come across a problem; when I re-size my browser, my website doesn't look the same. Everything resizes and moves itself so that everything is overlapping each other. I want my website to operate like this website: http://teixido.co/

This is my website: http://www.coopertimewell.com/

This is all my source code for html and css:

```css
@charset "utf-8";
 body {
  background-color: #DDDCDC;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
#anime {
  position: absolute;
  width: 38.3%;
  height: 100%;
  left: .5%;
  top: 1.25%;
}
#ct {
  position: absolute;
  width: 60%;
  left: 36%;
  top: 59%;
}
#official {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  left: 55%;
  top: 72%;
}
#home {
  position: absolute;
  left: 55.75%;
  top: 3.5%;
  width: 5.8%;
}
#home2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 55.75%;
  top: 3.5%;
  width: 5.8%;
  z-index: -1;
}
#thecoopertimes {
  position: absolute;
  left: 62%;
  top: 3.5%;
  width: 12.5%;
}
#thecoopertimes2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 62%;
  top: 3.5%;
  width: 12.5%;
  z-index: -1;
}
#aboutme {
  position: absolute;
  left: 75%;
  top: 3.5%;
  width: 8%;
}
#aboutme2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 75%;
  top: 3.5%;
  width: 8%;
  z-index: -1;
}
#contact {
  position: absolute;
  left: 83.5%;
  top: 3.5%;
  width: 6.8%;
}
#contact2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 83.5%;
  top: 3.5%;
  width: 6.8%;
  z-index: -1;
}
#games {
  position: absolute;
  left: 90.72%;
  top: 3.5%;
  width: 6.1%;
}
#games2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 90.72%;
  top: 3.5%;
  width: 6.1%;
  z-index: -1;
}
#home:hover {
  z-index: -9999999;
}
#home2:hover {
  z-index: 9999999;
}
#thecoopertimes:hover {
  z-index: -9999999;
}
#thecoopertimes2:hover {
  z-index: 9999999;
}
#aboutme:hover {
  z-index: -9999999;
}
#aboutme2:hover {
  z-index: 9999999;
}
#contact:hover {
  z-index: -9999999;
}
#contact2:hover {
  z-index: 9999999;
}
#games:hover {
  z-index: -9999999;
}
#games2:hover {
  z-index: 9999999;
}
#fb {
  position: absolute;
  top: 84%;
  left: 78%;
  width: 6%;
}
#insta {
  position: absolute;
  top: 84.25%;
  left: 83.5%;
  width: 6%;
}
#youtube {
  position: absolute;
  top: 84%;
  left: 89%;
  width: 6%;
}
#fb:hover {
  width: 6.5%;
  top: 83.5%;
  left: 77.7%;
}
#insta:hover {
  width: 6.5%;
  top: 83.9%;
  left: 83.2%;
}
#youtube:hover {
  width: 6.5%;
  top: 83.8%;
  left: 88.7%;
}
#text {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30%;
  left: 65%;
  top: 76%;
}
#bs2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
}
#pic {
  position: absolute;
  top: 300%;
  width: 25%;
  height: 55%;
}
#down {
  position: absolute;
  top: 88%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 5%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Home - CooperTimewell.com</title>
  <link href="coopertimewell/anime.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
    if (screen.width < 800) {
      window.location = "mobile.html"
    }
  </script>
  <meta name="description" content="This is just a website about me, and some stuff I'm interested in." />
</head>
<link href="indexstylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<body>
  <img id="anime" src="coopertimewell/jumper1.png" />
  <a href="http://www.coopertimewell.com">
    <img id="ct" src="coopertimewell/ct2.png" />
  </a>
  <img id="official" src="coopertimewell/official.png" />
  <div id="allbuttons">
    <div id="firstlot">
      <a href="http://www.coopertimewell.com/index">
        <img id="home" src="coopertimewell/buttons/home1.png" />
      </a>
      <a href="http://www.coopertimewell.com/thecoopertimes.html">
        <img id="thecoopertimes" src="coopertimewell/buttons/coopertimes1.png" />
      </a>
      <a href="http://www.coopertimewell.com/aboutme.html">
        <img id="aboutme" src="coopertimewell/buttons/aboutme1.png" />
      </a>
      <a href="http://www.coopertimewell.com/contact.html">
        <img id="contact" src="coopertimewell/buttons/contact1.png" />
      </a>
      <a href="http://www.coopertimewell.com/games">
        <img id="games" src="coopertimewell/buttons/games1.png" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="secondlot">
      <a href="http://www.coopertimewell.com">
        <img id="home2" src="coopertimewell/buttons/home22.png" />
      </a>
      <a href="http://www.coopertimewell.com/thecoopertimes.html">
        <img id="thecoopertimes2" src="coopertimewell/buttons/coopertimes22.png" />
      </a>
      <a href="http://www.coopertimewell.com/aboutme.html">
        <img id="aboutme2" src="coopertimewell/buttons/aboutme22.png" />
      </a>
      <a href="http://www.coopertimewell.com/contact.html">
        <img id="contact2" src="coopertimewell/buttons/contact22.png" />
      </a>
      <a href="http://www.coopertimewell.com/games">
        <img id="games2" src="coopertimewell/buttons/games2.png" />
      </a>
      <a href="http://www.facebook.com/cooper.timewell">
        <img id="fb" src="coopertimewell/fbicon.png" />
      </a>
      <a href="http://www.instagram.com/cooper_timewell">
        <img id="insta" src="coopertimewell/instaicon.png" />
      </a>
      <a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/2667cooper">
        <img id="youtube" src="coopertimewell/youtubeicon.png" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <img id="text" src="coopertimewell/text1.png" />
  <img id="pic" src="coopertimewell/duck.gif" />
  <a href="http://www.coopertimewell.com/#pic">
    <img id="down" src="coopertimewell/downie.png" />
  </a>
</body>

</html>
```

How do I optimize this code to work so that it repositions itself so it fits the browser for both mobile and web? Thankyou.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is **responsive web design.** You need to alter your CSS (and jS) so that they can change the layout of your website according to the media it is being viewed on. Here are a few tips about making a responsive design :

1. **Set the viewport**. This is done so that the CSS pixels match the number of **device independent pixels.** This allows the page to reflow content to match different screen sizes, whether rendered on a small mobile phone or a large desktop monitor. Like this :

   ```
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   ```
2. Do not use **absolute**. Using absolute positioning can ruin the look of the page and make content flow out of the viewport when the available space is a little less than what you've been developing on. Try yo use **relative** positioning so that elements on the page reflow and adapt according to the changes in viewport size.
3. Use **CSS3 Media Queries**. You can use these queries to place **conditions** on the way the page lays out, depending on the type of media it is being viewed on. For example :

   ```
   @media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
     /*The CSS when the maximum width is 300px*/
   }
   ```

   Read more [here.](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)
4. Make the website **degrade gracefully** or **enhance progressively**. Both these design concepts stress that your website should not heavily depend on new technology or optional technology to lay out your page. You should not use jS to size your viewport. Instead, use CSS. The website should display **acceptably well** on platforms where new technology is not available or is disabled.
5. Go for **cross platform consistency.** Using `normalize.css` or `mordernizr.js` you can make the website display more consistently across platforms by making them display the native elements consistently and using feature detection.

Have a look at this [article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/set-the-viewport?hl=en).

Comment: Would you be able to make a version of my website with these changes enabled, or will this take too long?

Comment: @CooperTimewell It takes time and testing to make a website responsive. I can only guide you in the right direction.

Comment: With great dev tools available in the latest browsers, it should be a good experience.

Comment: Changing all my 'absolute' into 'relative' has not worked; everything is off the screen? How do I fix this?

Comment: @CooperTimewell Changing all absolutes to relative will **not** work. You need to learn about laying out elements [here](http://www.learnlayout.com/).

Comment: Hey mate, sorry to bother you again but I'm just not getting it at all. Would you be able to explain how relative positioning works and how I can use it?